# Kiujn tabulludojn oni plej ofte ludas dum Esperantistaj renkontiĝoj?

Tags: culture

Esperanto estas internacia, do mi supozas ke la tabulludoj ludataj estas tre diversaj. Tamen, ĉu ekzistas kelkaj tabulludoj kiuj estas aparte popularaj, kaj kiuj ili estas?

Answer (score 4):

Laŭ mia sperto en esperantaj eventoj oni ludas ĉian ajn ludon kaj la populareco de ludo spegulas ĝian popularecon ekster esperantujo. Tamen mi pensas ke estas kelkaj ludoj kiuj aparte bone funkcias en esperanta medio ĉar ili ne bezonas tradukon:

- [Dixit](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/39856/dixit) estas bona ĉar ĝi ne havas tekston en la ludo, ĝi estas facile lernebla kaj ĉiu devas almenaŭ iomete paroli laŭvice. Tiel ĝi helpas lerni la lingvon.
- Mi vidas [Jungle Speed](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/8098/jungle-speed) ofte, eble pro tio ke ĝi estas simpla kaj tre portebla.
- Diversaj ludoj kun la pecoj de [Icehouse](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/225/icehouse). Tio estas piramidaj pecoj por kio ekzistas multe da ludoj.

Kvankam ĝi ne vere estas *tabul*ludo, indas mencii [Homlupon](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homlupo_(ludo)). Ĝi estas pli kiel simpla rolludo kiun oni povas ludi kun tre granda nombro de homoj. Ne estas tabulo kaj ĝi funkcias nur per parolado. Tiu ludo estas ege populara en esperantaj aranĝoj kaj ĝi iĝas kvazaŭ aparta granda parto de la esperanta kulturo.

Comment: Mi timus ludi Dixit en Esperanto :-o Kvankam ĝi devas esti fabela por ekzerciĝi en esperanta vortoprovizo, ĝi ofte dependas je tiel subtilaj signifoj!